# Is set theory's definition of function application cheating?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

If you go through a book on introductory set theory you'll usually see something like "We take $f(x) = y$ as an abbreviation for $(x, y) \in f$."

Fair enough. If you then move forward by replacing any instance of $f(a) = b$ with $(a, b) \in f$ or vice versa, where $a$ and $b$ don't themselves include function application then we expect everything will work out.

But this is not how any practitioner will actually work. Once that equality sign is there, the user is going to start substituting $f(a)$ for $b$, because that's what you do with equality. Furthermore, common expressions like $f(u) = g(v)$ or $g(f(x)) = y$ can't be expanded robotically without additional rules, since we aren't given a meaning for $(u, g(v)) \in f$ or $(f(x), y) \in g$. It's not tough to figure out what those must mean, but it seems like something worth mentioning when you introduce the notation.

At this level, I don't think anyone really wants to go through a whole metatheoretical exposition just to justify the practical use of the $f(x) = y$ definition, but it does seem a bit cavalier to just throw it out there with no caveats. Especially when something like "define $f(x)$ as the big-Union of $f$'s image of $x$" is right there, and you get substitution, composition, etc. for free.

Am I missing some nice metatheorem about first-order logic that justifies using this definition of equality like actual equality and using $f(x)$ like a set (like a variant of how Extension by Definition is used to give names to the empty set, binary union, etc.) or is this really a "cheat"?

EDIT: Corrected what I was calling "Skolemization" to be "Extension by Definition".

Comment: Not exactly... $(x,y) \in f$ holds in general for relations. When f is a function, we have that for every x there is a unique y such thath... Thus, we are licensed to use the symbol $f(x)$ to name it, that amounts to $(x, f(x)) \in f$.

Comment: The formal way is: having $\exists ! y ((x,y)\in f)$ we introduce the symbol $f(x)=y \leftrightarrow (x,y)\in f$.

Comment: The meta-theorem is called definitional extension of the language.

Comment: "Extension by definitions" is what I'm looking for. So essentially just another form of naming empty set, etc. because you have an existence proof of $\forall x, \exists! y, (x, y) \in f$ you maybe abuse notation a bit and introduce a function symbol with the same name.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an abuse of notation, it's an [extension by definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions). Translation from the language with the new symbol to the original language is defined recursively.

Comment: I guess the abuse you're referring to is reusing the name $f$, but it turns out to create no ambiguity in expressions of first-order logic because the two symbols have different arities.

Comment: Does this work conditionally? Like "if $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ then for any $x \in A$, $P(f(x))$"?

Comment: On, I understand the problem. The issue is that just because two things are logically equivalent - does mean that they are syntactically equivalent. You cannot always substitute Logically Equivalent expressions into each other in sentences. This is one of the ways that logical equivalence and equality are distinct.

Comment: @GregoryBush I've wondered about that too. My understanding is that we technically treat such "conditional notation" as unconditional, assigning it a "dummy value" like the empty set when the conditions are not met. This justifies the extension by definitions, but then we have to make sure our theorems don't depend on the choice of dummy value, by making sure that the notation is only "used" when the conditions are met.

Comment: By the way, in set theory with functions as sets, we can do a single definitional extension to get a function symbol $\operatorname{apply}(f,x)$ and then view the notation "$f(x)$" as shorthand for this.

Comment: @Karl Ok, having a function symbol for $apply$ makes everything easy then. It might not be a useful set if $f$ isn't a function or $x$ isn't in the domain, but it doesn't matter because you don't use it that way. Pretty much like most other set theory constructions.

Comment: @Karl Thinking about this some more, I think the abuse of notation would have more to do with f being a variable but also by definitional extension a constant of the extended language. For example proving $f = g \rightarrow f(x) = g(x)$ would be problematic since the $f$ and $g$ on the right would be constants that couldn't be substituted for.

Comment: The metatheorem is a bit intricate, but that's life. You will find it, for example, in Ebbinghaus, Flum, and Thomas, *Mathematical Logic* (UTM, 2nd ed), sec. VIII.3. I don't know if they "really want[ed] to go through [the] whole metatheoretical exposition", but they did anyway. (Also in Shoenfield, *Mathematical Logic*, sec.4.5.)

Comment: The [Hilbert $\varepsilon$ symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_calculus) provides a general approach to implicit definitions like the definition of function application. You can also consider an operator (say $\iota$) corresponding to Russell's more restricted notion of [definite description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description). In either case, if you want to view this purely as a matter of syntax, then you need to be careful as it can be explosive: see the paper by Adrian Mathias cited in the $\varepsilon$ link for a demonstration of how Bourbaki got it badly wrong.

Comment: P.S., I think Russell's discussion of definition description (cited in my previous comment) is one of the best philosophical discussions of the issue at hand: it shows how you can always get rid of the "cheating": but the results can be incredibly verbose.

Comment: Suggestion: Suppose we have sets $D,C$ and $g$ such that $g\subset D\times C$ and $\forall x\in D: \exists!y\in C:[(x,y)\in g ]$. Then $\exists f:[\forall x\in D: \forall y\in C:[f(x)=y \iff (x,y)\in g]]$. Then we can obtain: $\forall x\in D:f(x)\in C$

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about the comments for a while, I'll take a stab at answering my own question.

To clarify, this is about the seemingly common practice in expositions of axiomatic set theory of defining $f(x)\ \dot=\ y$ as mere *notation* for $(x, y) \in f$ instead of actually defining function application (I put a dot over the equals sign to clarify that this is a notational convention, not equality in the base language of FOL+ZFC) then later "forgetting" it's just notation and using $f(x)$ by itself as denoting a set or $\dot=$ to justify substitutions.

For example, we might later see $(\forall f \in A\rightarrow B)(\forall g \in B\rightarrow C)(\forall x \in A)(g(f(x)) \in C)$ in the same development, which doesn't include $\dot=$ at all and uses $f(x)$ as a set directly.

So how do we justify this? If we attempt to use the fact $f$ is a function to extend our theory's first-order language to include $\dot f$ as a function symbol definitionally (I put a dot over it to clarify it's a new symbol in the language, not the variable $f$), then we run into an immediate problem: $\dot f$ is a function constant, like $\varnothing$ or $\cup(x,y)$. We can't quantify over it. Alternatively, if we expand our syntax to allow function variables, then we are no longer in first-order logic. So we are missing something in the transition from the $\dot =$ definition to actual use.

Kurt pointed out what it is in the comments: the definition of function application.

Let's try to actually apply extension by definition on function $f$. We want a proof of the form $(\forall x...)(\exists! y)R(x,y)$. Let's start with $(\forall A)(\forall B)(\forall f \in (A \rightarrow B))(\forall x \in A)(\exists! y \in B) ((x, y) \in f)$. This doesn't quite match the form due to the bounded quantification. $$(\forall A)(\forall B)(\forall f)(\forall x)(\exists! y)[(f \in (A \rightarrow B) \land x \in A \implies x \in B \land (x, y) \in f) \land (f \not \in (A \rightarrow B) \lor x \not \in A \implies y = \varnothing)]$$ matches the form and is essentially equivalent. It just preserves the uniqueness of $y$ after the unique existential is moved past the bounds by giving it a default value when $f$ is not a function $A \rightarrow B$ or $x$ is not in its domain.

We end up with a new function constant in the extension $\text{apply}(A,B,f,x)$ with the defining axiom $(\forall A)(\forall B)(\forall f \in (A \rightarrow B))(\forall x \in A)[\text{apply}(A,B,f,x) \in B \land (x, \text{apply}(A,B,f,x)) \in f]$. I ignore the specification of the value of $\text{apply}$ when $f$ isn't a matching function or $x$ is outside of the domain, because we don't want to use it that way anyway.

If you only require that $f$ is a function generally and don't care about the domain and codomain you can define a similar $\text{apply}(f,x)$ without $A$ and $B$.

Then you can define the *notation* $f(x)$ to mean $\text{apply}(f,x)$ without any problems and proceed normally.

Which comes back to my initial question. It's easy enough to define function application in a way (like this or the big-Union of the image of $x$ under $f$, etc.) that works when used in practice, and it seems fundamental to a working definition of functions. Trying to skip over it notationally with $f(x) \dot = y$ seems like its skipping something that's actually important.

Comment: Somehow, you want $f(x)$ to be, in some sense, undefined if $x$ is not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Ideally you'd be able to prove that given a function $f$ and a value $x$ not in $f$'s domain that there is no $y$ such that $f(x) = y$, which you could do with the $\dot =$ definition, but not if $f(x)$ always unfolds to a term in your language.

Comment: Something as natural as being able to prove $f(x) = f(x)$ would then be dangerous because you could then show there is a y such that $f(x) = y$ when $x$ is out of $f$'s domain and reach a contradiction.

Comment: It does seem like if you adopt the $f(x) \dot = y$ as mere notation for $(x, y) \in f$ route, that you have to be vigilant to remember it's just notation, because $\dot =$ does then not work like actual equality (reflexivity fails in some cases e.g.), and if you adopt $f(x)$ defined as a term, then you should politely avoid talking about it unless $x$ is in $f$'s domain.

Comment: Re: $f(x)=f(x)$ being "dangerous." Yes. In my system, you cannot use the reflexivity axiom to introduce function images like $f(x)$. If you specify "$f(x)$", it must have been previously established that $f(x)$ is an element of  a set, i.e. statement of the form $f(x)\in S$.

Comment: I'll check out DC Proof. I like trying proof assistants!

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Just an initial impression but it's like your semantics is that variables are sets, $f(x)$ may be a set or something else like a special "undefined" value, and equality means not just equals, but "is a set", too. Then $f(x)$, even if if denotes a set may or may not have anything to do with the value of an applied function, but in the case where f is the graph of a function, you have an axiom that that says it's the set you expect.

Comment: (1) The Set predicate is used declare that an object is a set, i.e. an object to which the axioms of set theory can be applied. (2) To postulate the existence of an arbitrary function f  mapping elements of set x to elements of set y, you simply state: ALL(a):[a $\in$ x => f(a) $\in$ y]. If z $\notin$  x, then this definition of f simply cannot be applied for z. There is no "undefined" value as such.

Comment: ... (3) The general axiom of reflexivity of  can be  applied to any previously introduced free variable. Free variables can only be introduced by axiom, premise or existential specification (not by universal specification). The Axiom of Set Equality can only be applied for objects that are declared to be a set. As above, reflexivity of function images like f(z) can only be a applied if f(z) was previously  stated to be an element of a set,.

Comment: I was thinking more about what a model of your theory would look like. Presumably there's one where $f(x) = f(x)$ is false for some $f$ and $x$ but $x = x$ is true for all $x$ and $P(f(x)) \implies f(x) = f(x)$ is true for all $f$ and $x$. So you have some domain of values for variables (I called it sets but maybe not that) that $f(x)$ can fall outside of sometimes and things like atomic predicates and equality can only ever apply to values. It reminds me a bit of how SQL works with NULL.

Comment: You won't be able to prove $f(x)\neq f(x)$ for any $f$ and $x$ in DC Proof.  Also, if $x$ is not in the domain of function $f$, then you will not be able to determine the truth value of $f(x)=y$ for any $y$.